# vk_api module: User authorization failed: access_token has expired

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую модуль Python vk_api для взаимодействия с API Вконтакте. Примерно две недели назад авторизация стала отпадывать через сутки:

```
vk_api.VkApi(str(vk_login), str(vk_password), app_id=6287487)
```

через примерно сутки получаю ошибку:

```
User authorization failed: access_token has expired.
```

Если перезапустить авторизацию- все работает еще сутки.
Просьба подсказать способы заставить авторизацию держаться больше суток, либо подсказать модуль, которым можно заменить vk_api.